# Cómo quitar columnas del Print ? - Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buen día !

Tengo una tabla que contiene fotos y botones, etc. Esa tabla tiene un botón en la parte superior de **imprimir**, pero actualmente me las está imprimiendo con fotos, botones, etc.
Alguna recomendación del cómo quitar columnas al momento de imprimir ?

Gracias [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día:

Minutos mas tarde. 
Encontré la solución.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html

saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero debes agregar la parte esencial de los enlaces en tu respuesta, recuerda que este puede eliminarse y la pregunta ya no tendría la información, revisar [ask], te sugerimos editar tu respuesta con esta información, de esta forma será de mucha ayuda para la comunidad, saludos.